# How to manually increment in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, methods, increment

Given an array of objects, whats a more "manual" way of incrementing to find the object that occurs greater than 2 times? I've figured out two "shorter" methods of solving this but am wondering if there's a more abstract way, a way to "manually" increment with a counter of some sort... The result should return an array of contributors that occur more than twice.

i.e. `[#<Author:0x00007ff447a94c58 @name="Alice Allison">, #<Author:0x00007ff447a94c08 @name="Bob Bryce">]`

```
contributors = 
=> #[<Author:0x00007fccbc220a48 @name="Dassey Davidson">,
#<Author:0x00007fe1d9374de0 @name="Alice Allison">,
#<Author:0x00007fe1d9374de0 @name="Alice Allison">,
#<Author:0x00007fe1d9374de0 @name="Alice Allison">,
#<Author:0x00007fe1d9374d90 @name="Bob Bryce">,
#<Author:0x00007fe1d9374d90 @name="Bob Bryce">,
#<Author:0x00007fe1d9374d90 @name="Bob Bryce">]


# method 1:
def contributing_authors
  contributors.select do |contributor| 
    contributors.count(contributor) > 2 
  end.uniq
end 


# method 2:
def new_contributing_authors
  storage = []
  contributors.each do |contributor|
    if contributors.count(contributor) > 2
      storage << contributor
    end
  end 
  storage.uniq
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Array#count` in a loop is suboptimal (complexity `O(N^2)`).

To increment a variable, you use `v += 1`. This is the natural way of doing it:

```
counts = contributors.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |contributor, counts|
  counts[contributor] += 1
}
more_than_twice = counts.select { |contributor, count| count > 2 }.keys
```

Comment: `.keys`? Does `select` return `Hash`?

Comment: @Fabio: When applied to a `Hash`, [yes](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/select).

Comment: A variant of the calculation of `counts` that was popular when I was a kid is `counts = contributors.each_with_object({}) { |contributor, counts| 
counts[contributor] = (counts[contributor] || 0) + 1 }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Author
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

```
contributors = [["Dassey Davidson", 1], ["Alice Allison", 3],
                ["Bob Bryce", 3]].
  flat_map { |name, reps| [Author.new(name)] * reps }
  #=> [#<Author:0x00005bd271073ce0 @name="Dassey Davidson">,
  #    #<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">,
  #    #<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">,
  #    #<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">,
  #    #<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">,
  #    #<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">,
  #    #<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">]
```

We can object the desired array as follows.

```
contributors.group_by(&:itself).
             select { |_, arr| arr.size > 2 }.
             keys
  #=> [#<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">,
  #    #<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">]
```

See [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Object#itself](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Object.html#method-i-itself) and [Hash#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) (which, unlike `Array#select` and `Enumerable#select`, returns a hash).

The steps are as follows:

```
g = contributors.group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {#<Author:0x00005bd271073ce0 @name="Dassey Davidson">=>
  #      [#<Author:0x00005bd271073ce0 @name="Dassey Davidson">],
  #    #<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">=>
  #      [#<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">,
  #       #<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">,
  #       #<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">],
  #    #<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">=>
  #      [#<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">,
  #       #<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">,
  #       #<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">]}
```

```
h = g.select { |_, arr| arr.size > 2 }
  #=> {#<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">=>
  #      [#<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">,
  #       #<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">,
  #       #<Author:0x00005bd271073c68 @name="Alice Allison">],
  #    #<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">=>
  #      [#<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">,
  #       #<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">,
  #       #<Author:0x00005bd271073bc8 @name="Bob Bryce">]}
```

```
h.keys
  #=> <as above>
```

This approach, using `Enumerable#group_by`, and @Amadan's, using the form of `Hash::new` that uses a default value of zero, are the two standard ways of dealing with problems of this kind. The choice is largely a matter of taste. I generally prefer the `Hash::new` method, but either will do.

Some time ago I proposed that a method [Array#difference](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815) be added to the Ruby core.<sup>1</sup> Alas, the proposal went nowhere. Here it would provide a simple solution:

```
(contributors.difference((contributors.uniq * 2).flatten)).uniq
```

<sup>1 Not to be confused with the method [Array#difference](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-difference) that made its debut in v2.6.</sup>